# How to reverse Java color transform from RGB to CIEXYZ / CIELAB

Tags: java, colors, color-space, lab-color-space

My ultimate goal is to convert RGB to CIELAB, do some color averaging, and then convert back. So my assumption is that if, due to runtime circumstances, there is only a single color input, i.e. *no averaging*, then the transform output should be the exact same as the RGB input, but this isn't the case.

The CIELAB colorspace uses an intermediate transform to CIEXYZ colorspace (which is part of the JDK). That transform appears to be non-reversible or lossy? Is this correct? Or is there something wrong with my assumptions or implementation? Should I be using another method to work with these colors?

Test and output below. Why aren't rgb and rgb2 the same color?

```
private static final ColorSpace CIEXYZ =ColorSpace.getInstance(ColorSpace.CS_CIEXYZ);    
@Test
    public void testCiexyz() {
        float[] rgb = new float[] {0.15686275f, 0.2f, 0.20784314f};
        LOGGER.debug("rbg: {}",rgb);
        float[] xyz = CIEXYZ.fromRGB(rgb);
        LOGGER.debug("xyz: {}",xyz);
        float[] rgb2 = CIEXYZ.toRGB(xyz);
        LOGGER.debug("rbg2: {}",rgb2);
    }
```

Output

```
    09:46:59.762 [main] DEBUG org.phomos.sampler.ColorTest - rbg: [0.15686275, 0.2, 0.20784314]
        09:46:59.875 [main] DEBUG org.phomos.sampler.ColorTest - xyz: [0.02709961, 0.030670166, 0.0289917]
        09:46:59.911 [main] DEBUG org.phomos.sampler.ColorTest - rbg2: [0.12155337, 0.1400473, 0.1430228]
```

Comment: After having been concerned with color spaces a bit, my first impulse when I encounter them is to hold my ears shut and scream "laaalaalaaa" and pretend I didn't see them. They are something that is *impossible* to get right. Seriously. I thought that the `ColorSpace#toCIEXYZ` and `fromCIEXYZ` methods might be a simple solution here (called on the `sRGB` color space, of course), but no avail. I'm curious whether someone can write a "good" answer to that one, so +1.

Comment: Yea from what I read Colorspaces are just ridiculously complicated and varied. Which is why I specified that perhaps the transformation is indeed lossy. I have no doubt that the JDK code is likely correct, but I cant help but think that there has to be a proper way to do what I'm attempting.

Comment: There are things like the library around https://github.com/igd-geo/pcolor/blob/master/de.fhg.igd.pcolor.test/src/de/fhg/igd/pcolor/test/ConversionTest.java (but **note** that this project is no longer maintained). The test is roughly related to your question, with forward<->backward conversions and such. But sorting out the right classes/parameters there would be tedious. I also think that there *should* be an easy way using the Java standard API, without having to depend on an old, complex lib. Let's see whether a colorimetry expert stumbles over this question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the following Java class...

https://imagej.nih.gov/ij/plugins/download/Color_Space_Converter.java

The inner class ColorSpaceConverter has colorspace conversions that all appear to be mathematically reversible. I hacked away the outer class since it's part of some monolithic gui app, which I don't need.

I learned a bit about the CIEXYZ and CIELAB colorspaces a long the way, but still nothing that explains why the standard JDK classes don't work like they should. Either way, the above code works!